How i can patent an idea and concepts? Can I patent a new idea and new concepts?
So I have many ideas and concepts to take patents so there we can patent an idea and concepts. How much will it cost to take patent an idea.
Is it too much costly. I am individual from India

You can’t patent an “idea”. What is patented are uses of an idea to achieve something. Because of your level of English I don’t know if you have many patentable inventions or just abstract ideas.
You might decide which idea has the most promising financial outcome and focus on just that one. With the resources on line and books you can buy it won’t cost much to learn much more about patents than you know now. That can help you evaluate your options.
It usually is expensive.
